# Error on a xml header declaration statement?

Tags: xml

Could someone explain me the difference between the two header declarations below?

1. `?xml version=\"1.0\"`
2. `?xml version="1.0"`

We are sending data to a web services running on a windows server from a unix machine but only option 2 works.

Comment: The first one is invalid. It has escaped quotes, as if it were encoded into a string for another programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration has the quotes (") escaped with a backslash (\) which is not how you escape quotes in XML.